# Learning about ArcMap's Tracking Analyst tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tracking-analyst

I was examining the ArcMap toolboxes to learn more about their functions and found the Tracking Analyst tool.

Does anybody have examples of how can this function is used and when best to use it?

Answer (score 7):

[Tracking Analyst](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006300000001000000.htm) is an extension designed for mapping objects that move or change status through time.

When combined with [Tracking Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/tracking-server/index.html), it can provide a powerful means to distribute live tracking data via the web.  I think a great example is t[his tracking application for traffic](http://screencast.com/t/VprQAVfSumd), with a nice flex designed dashboard that someone with no GIS experience can easily use.
See the [demos](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/trackinganalyst/demos.html) for more info on its capabilities.

I think you need to elaborate on your Q more.  I do not see why you need TA to achieve concatenating a date and time field.  See this [whitepaper](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Geoprocessing-Model-and-Script-Tool-Gallery/details?entryID=F3368746-1422-2418-A061-D00793D7F9F0) on how to achieve this without extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better of using the Animation built-in to ArcGIS 10

A quick intro might help.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_animations/00090000006p000000/

Answer (score 1):

At ArcGIS 10, much of the desktop functionality of Tracking Analyst can be achieved via the built-in time support. You can take a look at the [Esri Training blog posting](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/esritrainingmatters/archive/2010/09/08/mapping-time-in-arcgis-10.aspx) to get a quick walkthrough.